# Login to registry with Docker Python SDK (docker-py)

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I am trying to use the Docker Python API to login to a Docker cloud:

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#creating-a-client1

What is the URL? What is the Port?

I have tried to get it to work with cloud.docker.com, but I am fine with any registry server, so long as it is free to use and I can use it to upload Docker images from one computer and run them on another.

I have already got everything running using my own locally hosted registry, but I can’t seem to figure out how to connect to a server. It’s kind of ridiculous that hosting my own registry is easier than using an existing registry server.

My code looks like this, but I am unsure what the args.* parameters should be:

```
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url=args.docker_registry)
client.login(username=args.docker_user, password=args.docker_password)
```

I’m not sure what the base_url needs to be so that I can log in, and the error messages are not helpful at all.

Can you give me an example that works?

Answer (score 4):

The `base_url` parameter is the URL of the Docker server, not the Docker Registry.

Try something like:

```
from docker.errors import APIError, TLSParameterError

try:
   client = docker.from_env()
   client.login(username=args.docker_user, password=args.docker_password, registry=args.docker_registry)
except (APIError, TLSParameterError) as err:
   # ...
```

Comment: I have used docker.from_env() to connect to my locally hosted docker registry. How do I switch back to a public one?
Also, what should args.docker_registry look like?

Comment: docker.from_env() only connects you to a Docker server.  The `registry` argument to the login() method connects you to the specified Registry URL.

Comment: I know. What should the registry URL look like? For instance, "https://cloud.docker.com" is the URL of a website that hosts a registry, but setting registry="https://cloud.docker.com" gives an error. What do I need to do to make it accept the registry?

Comment: What is the error message?  The URL should be the same used with the `docker login` command.

Comment: there are different error messages for different urls. I didn't manage to make it work with cloud.docker.com, but I got it to work by switching to quay.io, which I can upload to with registry='quay.io'

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I have logged in to Docker using Python:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
client.login(username='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD', email='EMAIL',
                       registry='https://index.docker.io/v1/')
```

and here's what it returns:

```
{'IdentityToken': '', 'Status': 'Login Succeeded'}
```

So, that means it has been logged in successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't figured out what the registry of cloud.docker.com is called, but I got it to work by switching to quay.io as my registry server, which works with the intuitive registry='quay.io'